# In a binary tree, for every node the difference between the number of nodes in the left and right

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

In a binary tree, for every node the difference between the number of nodes in the left and right subtrees is at most 2. If the height of the tree is h>0, then the minimum number of nodes in the tree is.

My Understanding:Total nodes in that tree = no.of left subtree nodes + no.of right subtree nodes + 1 ( root node)

= no.of left subtree nodes + ( no.of left subtree nodes - 2 ) + 1

= no.of left subtree nodes + no.of left subtree nodes - 2  + 1

= 2 * no.of left subtree nodes - 1

H(n) = 2*H(n-1)-1
here i solved it using substitution but when i put h(0)=1 it gives only 1 as answer not in terms of H. can you please help why i can't put h(0)=1 as my base condition because it also satisfy the given binary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recurrence assumes that your tree has nodes.

`H(n) = 2*H(n-1) - 1` assumes `H(n-1)` is defined. But for n=0, `H(n-1) = H(-1)` which doesn't make sense. So you need to establish your base case for `H(0)` which you can do with a simple argument.

So your recurrence would be the value of `H` when n = 0 and `H(n) = 2*H(n-1) - 1` if `n > 0`.

Also, you should use >= in your argument. The left subtree could actually be bigger.

no. of left subtree nodes + no. of right subtree nodes + 1 >= no. of left subtree nodes + (no. of left subtree nodes - 2) + 1

Answer (score 1):

When n=1, in the minimal case the left subtree from the root has 1 node, but the right subtree has 0 nodes and not -1 nodes like your reasoning would suggest.

For n>1, your reasoning is correct.

So you need to assume H(1)=2, and then you get the right results.